# How to capture constructor arguments using PowerMockito

Tags: junit, mockito, powermock, powermockito

```
class A {
   public B getB(){
      // somehow get argType1 and argType2
      return new B(argType1, argType2);
   }
}

class B{
   public B(Type1 t1, Type2 t2){
     // something
   }
}
```

I want to Test `A`, and verify that constructor of `B` is getting called for expected values of `argType1` and `argType2`.

How can i do this using PowerMockito?

Is there a way to pass argumentCaptor like this:

```
whenNew(B.class).withArguments(argType1Captor, argType2Captor).thenReturn(somemock);
```

if this do this, `argType1Captor` gets both the values

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved it by doing this

```
PowerMockito,verifyNew(B.class).withArgument(expectedArgType1, expectedArgType2)
```

Comment: expectedArgType1 is actualy argument right? Not ArgumentCaptor ??

Comment: You are indeed not capturing the arguments. You're only saying what arguments they should be. There's a subtle, but important difference.

Answer (score 4):

Dhrumil Upadhyaya, your answer (admittedly the only one offered) doesn't solve the question you asked! I think you might want to do something like:

```
public class MyTest {
   private ArgType argument;

   @Before
   public void setUp() throws Exception {
       MyClass c = mock(MyClass.class);

       whenNew(MyClass.class).withAnyArguments()
                             .then((Answer<MyClass>) invocationOnMock -> {
                argument = (ArgType) invocationOnMock.getArguments()[0];
                return c;
            } 
        );
    }
}
```

It's not an elegant solution but it will capture the argument(s) passed to the  constructor. The advantage over your solution is that if argument is a DTO then you can inspect it to see if it contains the values you were expecting.